# How can I keep from giving in to a clerk that tries to get me to sign up for a credit card when I know that getting the card will hurt my credit?

Tags: credit-card

It seems like more and more retailers are shoving credit cards down your throat. What's the best response I can give to a clerk when they keep asking me to sign up for a credit card that I don't want that I know will hurt my credit score?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a personal finance question. Any adult should already know how to say "no."

Comment: Any adult should already know how to [insert any number of topics about personal finance]. I think there is room here for this question but I will abstain from voting to reopen, I don't have a strong opinion, and I didn't put much effort into my answer. I do think that salespeople tend to prey on the general tendency to be polite, that's why I gave a quick answer instead of voting to close.

Comment: But as always, if members feel this is really on topic, a vote to reopen is the way to go. The question would be just at home at the automotive site. Just a bit of change to advice to avoid giving in to pushy car salesman.

Comment: Tell them that you have to cut him off, since the judge ordered you not to discuss credit card offers with store clerks, "after what happened".  If they press you for what happened, say you'd rather not talk about it, but that he recovered fully.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"No, thanks!"

You really shouldn't say any more than that to a salesperson because when you give a reason, the next step is to try to talk around that reason/concern. By saying "no" very simply, you end the conversation.

Sometimes people are hard of hearing or don't comprehend "no", so you may have to repeat yourself.

Comment: ["No" is a complete sentence](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-fallible-mind/201204/no-is-complete-sentence), but we usually add ", thank you" to be polite.

Answer (score 2):

"I am sorry that your job may depend on closing a certain amount of credit card initiations, but I am far too financially savvy to enter into such a poor deal.  Thanks and have a great day."

Or my favorite:  "No!"  I have a very loud voice so that might help.

Comment: Pretty presumptuous to blindly assume the offer is a "poor deal", wouldn't you say? :D

Comment: The goal is to not sign up, and to not be bothered. "Poor deal" has a good chance to achieve the goal.